# How to call wordpress custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

i make a custom post type in WordPress  and i also make its separate two pages single-acme_product.php, archive-acme_product.php but the issue is when i upload the post from custom post type its show index.php

here is my code of function

```
function new_post_type_wp(){

    register_post_type('acme_product',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Products'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Product')
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
            )
        );
}
add_action('init','new_post_type_wp');
```

please tell me how to i navigate my custom post to specific custom page i also read wordpress codex its very help full i follow its method but my issue is same kindly help me

reference link https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: Usman its not clear what problem you are facing. Can you please add more information.

Comment: dear i make a custom post type and i just want i show my custom posts on single-acme_product.php , the issue i make a separate page single-acme_product.php for custom posts  reference link https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types  but instead the posts show on single-acme_product.php they show on index.php i just want to show these post on my single-acme_product.php you got it ??

Comment: Yes I am getting it thanks for more info.  Your custom post type should not appear on index.php. Please use this link to generate cpt code http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/ and make sure you set up rewrite option so your custom post type is available at /cpt/single-item-name

Comment: dear my cpt code is work prefect but the issue the posts of cpt not navigate single-spt.php and the link you send it also generate cpt i need just the cpt post navigate to single-cpt.php

Comment: go to wordpress dashboard, settings->permalink then save ( no need to change options ). And then try, if not let me know there is another thing to try

Comment: dear i already do this but the result is same

Comment: Brother it seemed to be something missing. Can you share URL of your website. And urls, expected url and url it is taking to?

Comment: you need to call the correct `CPT` query in your theme files e.g. `single-cpt.php ` or `single-acme_product.php` . can you show the code from there ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it for this custom post type in particular page?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'acme_product', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: actuality your code is perfect and the issue is in my theme i copy paste the default theme files and they work perfect and after that i know what the issue thanks dear you give me good code